# Creating a dictionary with list values from a queryset efficiently

Tags: python, django, performance, loops, dictionary

Given a set of objects returned from a queryset how can I construct a dictionary with one of the objects attributes as the key and and the object itself as the value?

The current code:

```
questions = Questions.objects.all()
parent_question = defaultdict(list)
section_question = defaultdict(list)

for question in questions:
    parent_question[question.parent_id].append(question)
    section_question[question.section_id].append(question)
```

Can I improve the efficiency somehow by remove the loop? Using map or something? Or maybe modifying the query?  Or do I have to live with this?

Comment: You could try using `Blog.objects.values('id', 'name')` Check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: Can you add an overview of your data ?